# API not invoking the lambda based on the response from the lambda authorizer and return null message

Tags: node.js, postman, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I am trying to authenticate api based on the response from the Lambda authorizer. So i have created following stack:

1. Lambda function call 'Test-Lambda' which return some value
2. Created an API Gateway and attached to the 'Test-Lambda'
3. Now created a Authorizer Lambda which validate the request header and return the policy . Attached the same with API Gateway

Now after deployed the API, i tested via post man with the following parameter's

```
Key: Authorization
Value:allow
```

But in the response i am getting following output

```
{
    "message": null
}
```

Here is the Lambda Authorizer code. As i verified in the cloud watch logs, this is executing fine based on the request

```
module.exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
   const token = event.authorizationToken.toLowerCase();
   const methodArn = event.methodArn;
   console.log("Lambda Invoked")

   switch(token){
       case 'allow':
           return genertaeAuthResponse('user','Allow', methodArn);
       default:
          return  genertaeAuthResponse('user','Deny', methodArn);

   }

}

function genertaeAuthResponse(principalId, effect, methodArn) {
    const policyDocument= generatePolicyDocument(effect, methodArn);

    return {
        principalId,
        policyDocument

    }

}


function generatePolicyDocument(effect, methodArn){
    console.log("Lambda Invoked in the generatePolicyDocument", effect,methodArn)
    if(!effect || !methodArn) return null

    const policyDocument =  {
         Version: '2012-10-17',
         Statemnet: [{
             Action:'execute-api:Invoke',
             Effect: effect,
             Resource: methodArn

         }]

   };
   console.log("policyDocument in the generatePolicyDocument", policyDocument)
   return policyDocument

}
```

I seeing below response in the logs

```
 Version: '2012-10-17',
  Statemnet: [
    {
      Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
      Effect: 'Allow',
      Resource: 'arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-1:myresource'
    }
  ]
}
```

But i am not understanding why post man returns 'null', which usually returns for the 'fail' value ? It looks like the api gateway not invoking the lambda based on the response from the authorizer

Appreciate if anybody can help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Anybody please help on this?

Comment: still unclear what to do?

Comment: Hello @umdev how did u figure out this issue? I have a similar problem. It would be nice if you share your knowledge. thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html) the output should be:

```json
{
  "principalId": "<user>",
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-1:123456789012:<APIG-ID>/<path>"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Currently, your authorizer only returns the inner part with "Version" and "Statement" and not the full expected response